# Python 2D Array Sorting is not showing actual result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I am trying to sort a 2d array, i tried many ways but its not working .I don't know what's going on here

```
    from operator import itemgetter
    import pprint
    arr=[['0.55070000', '879.00000000'], ['0.55350000', '879.00000000'], ['0.55640000', '879.00000000'], ['0.56210000', '879.00000000'], ['0.56490000', '879.00000000'], ['0.56780000', '879.00000000'], ['0.57060000', '879.00000000'], ['0.54500000', '899.00000000'], ['0.56370000', '901.00000000'], ['0.53070000', '908.00000000'], ['0.57350000', '916.00000000'], ['0.55000000', '9172.00000000'], ['0.56300000', '939.00000000'], ['0.54490000', '94.00000000'], ['0.56040000', '96.00000000'], ['0.54960000', '999.00000000']]
    # sorted(floatarry, key=itemgetter(1))
    sorted(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
    pprint.pprint(arr)
    # from operator import itemgetter
    
    #############################################################
    # columnIndex = 1
    # # Sort 2D numpy array by 2nd Column
    
    # arr2D = np.array(arr)
    
    # sortedArr = arr2D[arr2D[:,columnIndex].argsort()]
    # print('Sorted 2D Numpy Array')
    # print(sortedArr)

result 
[['0.55070000' '879.00000000']
['0.55350000' '879.00000000']
['0.55640000' '879.00000000']
['0.56210000' '879.00000000']
['0.56490000' '879.00000000']
['0.56780000' '879.00000000']
['0.57060000' '879.00000000']
['0.54500000' '899.00000000']
['0.56370000' '901.00000000']
['0.53070000' '908.00000000']
['0.57350000' '916.00000000']
['0.55000000' '9172.00000000']
['0.56300000' '939.00000000']
['0.54490000' '94.00000000']
['0.56040000' '96.00000000']
['0.54960000' '999.00000000']]
```

last 4 and 5 no line showing wrong result

Comment: You are sorting on the second values which are still strings. you have to turn them into float values / int values first. check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting the array with strings. Convert them to `float` in the lambda function and then try -

> Note: Make sure to assign the output of the sorted function.

```
arr_sorted = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
arr_sorted
```

```
[['0.54490000', '94.00000000'],
 ['0.56040000', '96.00000000'],
 ['0.55070000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.55350000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.55640000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.56210000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.56490000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.56780000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.57060000', '879.00000000'],
 ['0.54500000', '899.00000000'],
 ['0.56370000', '901.00000000'],
 ['0.53070000', '908.00000000'],
 ['0.57350000', '916.00000000'],
 ['0.56300000', '939.00000000'],
 ['0.54960000', '999.00000000'],
 ['0.55000000', '9172.00000000']]
```

Add `reverse=True` in the `sorted` as a parameter if you want it sorted in descending order.

---

If you want to work on this array with more numeric operations after the sorting, then **I would advise first converting the complete array to float values**, and then doing the sorting OR other operations.

```
arr2 = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in arr]
arr_sorted = sorted(arr2, key=lambda x: x[1])
arr_sorted
```

```
[[0.5449, 94.0],
 [0.5604, 96.0],
 [0.5507, 879.0],
 [0.5535, 879.0],
 [0.5564, 879.0],
 [0.5621, 879.0],
 [0.5649, 879.0],
 [0.5678, 879.0],
 [0.5706, 879.0],
 [0.545, 899.0],
 [0.5637, 901.0],
 [0.5307, 908.0],
 [0.5735, 916.0],
 [0.563, 939.0],
 [0.5496, 999.0],
 [0.55, 9172.0]]
```

Comment: glad to help anytime

Answer (score 1):

The `sorted()` function is not changing the `arr` itself, it simply returns a sorted list that you then have to assign to some variable. So do it like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import pprint
arr=[['0.55070000', '879.00000000'], ['0.55350000', '879.00000000'], ...]
sorted_arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])
pprint.pprint(sorted_arr)
```

Comment: its not work.the result is same

Comment: Your list is already sorted well from the smallest value (879.00000000) to the largest (999.00000000), so no wonder you don't see any difference. If you want it sorted from largest to smallest instead, write `sorted_arr = sorted(arr,key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)`.